# pandas backfil and ffill with different values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I want to backfill and fill empty values with different/unique id e.g. if I have following DF

```
+----+------+
| Id | T_Id |
+----+------+
|  1 | nan  |
|  1 | nan  |
|  1 | nan  |
|  1 | 4    |
|  1 | nan  |
|  2 | nan  |
|  2 | 5    |
|  2 | 5    |
|  2 | nan  |
|  2 | nan  |
|  2 | 6    |
|  2 | 6    |
|  2 | 6    |
|  2 | nan  |
|  2 | nan  |
+----+------+
```

I want to fill empty values before each non null value by the same value paired with some string so it represent the time before value is not null. An for last occurrence ffill in same way.My Desired Output looks like this:

```
+----+------+
| Id | T_Id |
+----+------+
|  1 | 4a   |
|  1 | 4a   |
|  1 | 4a   |
|  1 | 4    |
|  1 | 5a   |
|  2 | 5a   |
|  2 | 5    |
|  2 | 5    |
|  2 | 6a   |
|  2 | 6a   |
|  2 | 6    |
|  2 | 6    |
|  2 | 6    |
|  2 | 6b   |
|  2 | 6b   |
+----+------+
```

Comment: Is there a case where you'd get a `6c`, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use multiple `fillna` with `ffill`, `bfill`

```
s = (df.T_Id.bfill()+'a').fillna(df.T_Id.ffill()+'b')
df['fill_T_Id'] = df.T_Id.fillna(s)

Out[214]:
    Id T_Id fill_T_Id
0    1  NaN        4a
1    1  NaN        4a
2    1  NaN        4a
3    1    4         4
4    1  NaN        5a
5    2  NaN        5a
6    2    5         5
7    2    5         5
8    2  NaN        6a
9    2  NaN        6a
10   2    6         6
11   2    6         6
12   2    6         6
13   2  NaN        6b
14   2  NaN        6b
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do:

```
w1=df['T_Id'].notna()
s=w1.cumsum().shift()
w2=s.eq(s.max())
df['T_Id']=df['T_Id'].bfill().ffill().astype(str)
df['T_Id']=df['T_Id']+np.select([w1,w2,~(w1|w2)],['','b','a'])
```

---

**Output**

```
print(df)
    Id T_Id
0    1   4a
1    1   4a
2    1   4a
3    1    4
4    1   5a
5    2   5a
6    2    5
7    2    5
8    2   6a
9    2   6a
10   2    6
11   2    6
12   2    6
13   2   6b
14   2   6b
```

Answer (score 2):

We can achieve it by

```
s=df['Id'].groupby([df['Id'],df['T_Id'].notnull().cumsum()]).ngroup()
df.T_Id=df.T_Id.fillna(df.groupby('Id')['T_Id'].apply(lambda x : x.ffill().bfill()).astype(str)+(s+97).map(chr))
df
Out[37]: 
    Id  T_Id
0    1  4.0a
1    1  4.0a
2    1  4.0a
3    1     4
4    1  4.0b
5    2  5.0c
6    2     5
7    2     5
8    2  5.0e
9    2  5.0e
10   2     6
11   2     6
12   2     6
13   2  6.0h
14   2  6.0h
```